# I have set my flutter app for deep links in Android, but when I tap on external link, it open my app as in-app popup. Why?

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

What I want to achieve is that if user tap on the link e.g. on Whatsapp:

HTTP://dev.mycompany.com/qr/asd89f7as98df78

This link will open my app supplied with the deep link.

But the issue is this link actually open my app inside the Whatsapp. So when I open the app switcher, it looks like there are two instances of my app opened. How can I fix this?

I suspect this has something to do with the way I configure my intent filter on Android Manifest. But I'm inexperienced with intent-filter. This is the current configuration for my intent filter(s):

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="dev.mycompany.com" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Is there anything I can do to fix the problem? The first intent filter is the default when I create the app. The second one is from copy pasting from solutions I find on stack overflow. But I don't think this is the fully correct solution. I don't want the app to can be opened as popup.

Comment: In its [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking) the `intent-filter` tag is preceded by a `meta-data` tag. check if that works.

Comment: @EhsanAskari ooh okay. yea I don't have that meta data. let me try again now and I will inform you the result.

Comment: @EhsanAskari I have tried it, and unfortunately, the app still opened as in-app popup from the caller app.